# How to use a for loop in HAProxy config

Tags: for-loop, acl, haproxy

I am trying to write an acl of the form

```
`%{ for path in <var_file> }
 acl my_acl capture.req.uri -m beg ${path}/ or -m str ${path}
 %{ endfor ~}
```

But I am running into this error `unknown keyword '%{' in 'frontend' section`

What am I missing